# Why are my session variables not multiplying together?

Tags: php

This is my first PHP project, and the html is working great. However, my variables in PHP don't seem to work, as the second page displays complete gibberish. The first page is mostly for filling in information, which I assume is working, and the second part shows the information, only using php. But I feel like my variables aren't working. Maybe there's some code I messed up? Does anyone know what's wrong?

page1.php (where the information gets filled in)

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Currency Calculator</title>
<style>
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

p {
  font-family:Arial;
}

a.button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;
    padding: 10px 24px;
    text-decoration: Arial;
    color: black;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

a.button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1> Convert currency to EUR </h1>

<form action="page2.php" method="get">
<p> Amount in euro: </p> 
<input type="number" name="amount" min="0" step=".01">
<br> <br>
<p> To which currency should it be converted? </p>
<select name="currency" id="currency">
<option value="0" selected>Select a currency</option>
  <option value="1.1011">US Dollar</option>
  <option value="1,5160">Canadian Dollar</option>
  <option value="0.8980">British Pound</option>
  <option value="10.5623">Swedish Crown</option>
  <option value="7.4551">Danish Crown</option>
  <option value="75.2170">Argentinian Peso</option>
  <option value="1.0670">Swiss Frank</option>
  <option value="1.6640">Australian Dollar</option>
  <option value="7.8811">Chinese Yuan</option>
  <option value="7.4892">Turkish Lira</option>
</select> 
<br> <br> <br>
<a href="page2.php" class="button">Convert!</a>
</form>

<?php

$_GET['amount'] = $am;

$_SESSION['x'] = $am;

$_GET['currency'] = $cur;

$_SESSION['y'] = $cur;

?>  

</body>
</html>
```

page2.php (where the calculations show)

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

p {
  font-family:Arial;
}
</style>
</head>
 <body>

 <?php

 $_SESSION['x'] * $_SESSION['y'] = $money;

 echo . $_SESSION['x'] . "<p> of your selected currency is equal to </p>" . $money . "<p>. </p><br>";
 echo "<p>1 EUR is equal to </p>" . $_SESSION['y'] . "<p> of your selected currency.</p>";

 ?>


 </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The variable being assigned to should be at the start `$money = $_SESSION['x'] * $_SESSION['y'];`

Comment: Why are you use session for this?

Comment: Writing to a session has to be confirmed with `session_write_close()`

Comment: You should really go and enable proper PHP error reporting first of all.

Comment: @Michel no, it doesn’t. PHP does that implicitly, when the script instance ends. With `session_write_close` you can do it _before_ that, but it is not mandatory.

Comment: `$_GET['amount'] = $am;` – what is that supposed to be? There is no variable `$am` defined anywhere before this point in your script. Same with `$_GET['currency'] = $cur;`. This is a) the wrong way around (you want to use `$_GET['amount']` to _read_ the value of the passed parameter, not _write_ to it), and b) in the wrong script - these GET parameters will exist only _after_ you submitted your form (unless you called `page1.php` _with_ such GET parameters already, which I rather doubt), so this belongs into the second script to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few logical and syntactical error in your code. I would recommend you to have a re-read of the article, tutorial you're using to learn the basics of programming and understand them properly ( functions, assignments etc first )

Page1.php

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Currency Calculator</title>
    <style>
    input[type=number] {
      -moz-appearance: textfield;
    }

    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }

    p {
      font-family:Arial;
    }

    a.button {
        -webkit-appearance: button;
        -moz-appearance: button;
        appearance: button;
        padding: 10px 24px;
        text-decoration: Arial;
        color: black;
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }

    a.button:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1> Convert currency to EUR </h1>

    <form action="page2.php" method="get">
    <p> Amount in euro: </p> 
    <input type="number" name="amount" min="0" step=".01">
    <br> <br>
    <p> To which currency should it be converted? </p>
    <select name="currency" id="currency">
    <option value="0" selected>Select a currency</option>
      <option value="1.1011">US Dollar</option>
      <option value="1,5160">Canadian Dollar</option>
      <option value="0.8980">British Pound</option>
      <option value="10.5623">Swedish Crown</option>
      <option value="7.4551">Danish Crown</option>
      <option value="75.2170">Argentinian Peso</option>
      <option value="1.0670">Swiss Frank</option>
      <option value="1.6640">Australian Dollar</option>
      <option value="7.8811">Chinese Yuan</option>
      <option value="7.4892">Turkish Lira</option>
    </select> 
    <br> <br> <br>
    <button type="submit" class="button">Convert!</a>
    </form> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

Page2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

p {
  font-family:Arial;
}
</style>
</head>
 <body>

 <?php

 $money =  $_GET['amount'] * $_GET['currency'] ;

 echo   $_GET['amount'] . "<p> of your selected currency is equal to </p>" . $money . "<p>. </p><br>";
 echo "<p>1 EUR is equal to </p>" .$_GET['currency'] . "<p> of your selected currency.</p>";

 ?>


 </body>
</html>
```

Above rectified code should work.